# Not able to purge/uninstall Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, graphics, cuda, gpu-driver

so this all started with installing CUDA 10.1 and then realizing my system didnt read any of the drivers at all. So i uninstalled CUDA, reinstalled version 9.1, deactivated secure boot, and then tried changing gpu under 'additional drivers' in 'software and updates'. However, nothing seemed to work. So i decided to purge everything, CUDA as well as NVidia drivers. But I am not able to purge any of the drivers either,the error is pasted below (Note:There are many more error messages, but these two cover the different types):

```
Package 'xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-415' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cuda-drivers : Depends: libnvidia-common-440 (>= 440.64.00) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Further, using sudo apt --fix-broken install gives me some of the following errors:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```